# Syncing BlazeDS messages across two webservers

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I have a Flex/BlazeDS webapp (pseudo content management system) with a Java backend running on 2 Weblogic 10.3 servers for load balancing and HA purposes.

Basically, I'm using AMF polling to update my app such that when a user opens a document from the search results, the corresponding row will display a locked icon across all user displays that currently have that document on the screen.

The problem I have is that if a user connected to Server A opens up document X, the locked icon will only appear on the screens of other users connected to Server A. The displays of users connected to Server B will not be updated. Is there any established paradigm or best practice to ensure that the locked update will propagate across all servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a database implemented lock (if you already are using a database in your application).

Another solution is to implement a publisher/subscriber scenario and to use the BlazeDS clustering feature, described [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=services_clustering_5.html). Using JGroups, BlazeDS can be configured to work in a cluster and a message created by a publisher (lock an document) will be propagated to all the publishers.

The BlazeDS messaging features are described [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/Part_Flex_Messaging_1.html). I still recommend the first version (the database).

For more "exotic" options you can try with ZooKeeper, Hazelcast etc. I would not use them in your case, however.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I've gone and implemented the JGroups solution

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use database locking as well (you only need a boolean flag and a clean transactional isolation) and a distributed JMS topic in order to dispatch the locking event to all other users. I don't know if and how you can do that with BlazeDS but it would be easy to setup this kind of architecture with [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org).

Basically, when a user requests a document, a transactional, server-side bean (say an EJB3) has to check if the resource is available, lock it and publish a lock event to the distributed JMS topic. Because the topic is distributed, the message would be dispatched across all your WebLogic nodes and all connected users, whatever is the cluster node they are connected to, would be informed of this event through long-polling consumers. GraniteDS has good support of WebLogic asynchronous servlets (see [GravityWebLogicServlet](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/java/api/org/granite/gravity/weblogic/GravityWebLogicServlet.html)) and it will give your users a much more *real-time* experience than with simple polling, and without compromising scalability (asynchronous servlets are meant to be used in this kind of setup).

Some additional resources:

- Real-time messaging [documentation](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.messaging.html) for GraniteDS.
- A short [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRLZcU-m6G8) about GraniteDS' clustering, HA and real-time messaging features (though with JBoss and a basic Chat application).

Even if you don't want or can't use GraniteDS in your project, I would recommend to consider this distributed JMS topic has the best and most reliable solution to your problem.